# Notepad++ Find strings 50 characters or longer between two vertical bars

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I would like to ask for help with the regular expression to use in Notepad ++ that will find any text that is 50 or longer, and is between 2 vertical bars?

Example:

```
060801113494|I am writing a string that is longer that 50 characters|1054.70|2020-12-10 10:27:20|My Test|10511078
```

I saw some examples and have this version, but it is not working:

```
 \|(?:(?!\|).){50,}
```

The string can contain special characters.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: You could exclude matching the bars and assert a closing one `\|\K[^|]{50,}(?=\|)` https://regex101.com/r/fd2VSp/1

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! your help has saved me long time of tedious search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `\|(?:(?!\|).){50,}` matches the leading `|` and does not make sure that there is a closing one.

You can match a pipe, then forget what is matched so far and continue matching 50 or more chars other than a `|` while asserting one at the end.

```
\|\K[^|]{50,}(?=\|)
```

**Explanation**

- `\|` Match a `|`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^|]{50,}` Match 50+ times any char except `|`
- `(?=\|)` Positive lookahead, assert a `|` at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/glVd0V/1)

[image]